# How can I extract text without repetition from nested <li> tags using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nested, html-lists

So, I want to copy-paste (possibily with the indentation preserved) the text in this page: ***https://numismatics.org/pella/id/price.1?lang=it***

I'm using BeautifulSoup 4, and the coin type description is nested under the *class = 'metadata_section'*, so I wrote my code and decided to find all the <li> tags, since every line is inside a <li> tag.

The problem is that **there are nested <li> tags, so the same lines are counted multiple times!**

*Plus, there is no indentation and multiple spaces are added, and I don't know how to remove them*.

My code:

```
#! python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://numismatics.org/pella/id/price.1?lang=it'
html = requests.get(url)
s = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

#Here I'm looking for the class that contains the descriptions
description = s.find(class_= 'metadata_section')

#Here I try to find all <li> tags inside said class:
labels = description.find_all('li')

#Here I show you how all the results are stored inside 'labels'. 
#You can see that if something is nested inside 'n' <li> tags, it is counted 'n' times:
print("---------------------------")
for k in range(len(labels)):
    print("%s" %k)
    print(labels[k].text)
    print("---------------------------")
```

I need everything, but I just need it once!
This is how I want the description to be saved into a .txt file:
(*even just printing it is ok. The links are not important, just the text and possibly the indentation*)

[image: Text I need to copy:]

Thanks in advance for your help, this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

You can try recursion to print the text in structured way:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

url = 'https://numismatics.org/pella/id/price.1?lang=it'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

def print_metadata(soup, lvl=0):
    out = ''
    for c in soup.contents:
        if isinstance(c, Tag) and c.name == 'ul':
            out += print_metadata(c, lvl)
        elif isinstance(c, Tag) and c.name == 'li':
            out += "\n" + "\t" * (lvl + 1)
            out += print_metadata(c, lvl + 1)
        elif isinstance(c, Tag):
            out += f'{c.get_text(strip=True)} '
        else:
            c = c.strip()
            if c:
                out += f'{c} '
    return out

out = print_metadata(soup.select_one('.metadata_section'))
# remove empty lines:
out = re.sub(r'\n\t*\n', '\n', out)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
Descrizione del tipo 
        Autorità emittente 
                Autorità emittente: Alessandro Magno  
                        Dinastia: Dinastia argeade  
                        Stato: Regno di Macedonia  
                Stated Authority: Alessandro Magno  
                        Dinastia: Dinastia argeade  
                        Stato: Regno di Macedonia  
        Arco cronologico: 336 BCE - 323 BCE 
        Nominale: Tetradramma  
        Geografico 
                Zecca: Anfipoli (Valore incerto)  
                Regione: Europe -- Macedon -- Strymonian and Bottiaean District 
        Materiale: Argento  
        Tipo d'oggetto: Moneta  
        Dritto 
                Tipo: Head of beardless Heracles right wearing lion skin headdress 
                Divinità: Eracle  
                Divinità: Zeus  
        Rovescio 
                Legenda: ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡΟΥ 
                Simbolo(LeftField): prow r. 
                Tipo: Zeus seated on stool-throne left, eagle on outstretched right hand, sceptre in left hand 
        TypeSeries: Price (1991)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `find` you can use `select` with css selector to get only the top-level `li` elements.

**Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://numismatics.org/pella/id/price.1?lang=it'
html = requests.get(url)
s = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

#Here I'm looking for the class that contains the descriptions
labels = s.select('div.metadata_section > ul > li')
#Here I show you how all the results are stored inside 'labels'. 
#You can see that if something is nested inside 'n' <li> tags, it is counted 'n' times:
print("---------------------------")
for k in range(len(labels)):
    print("%s" %k)
    print(labels[k].text)
    print("---------------------------")
```